# Are prepared statements needed to fetch value

Tags: mysql

Are prepared statements needed to fetch a value?  If so, I can't find a reference.  I am using prepared statements to write to MYSQL.  Here is my working code. Thanks

```
//Check that Email matches Password, then get First Name and start session
if ($getFname = mysqli_fetch_assoc(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT userFname FROM users   WHERE userEmail = '$userEmail' and userPassword = '$userPassword'"))) {

    //Grab first name
    $data = $getFname['userFname'];

    //assign unique session ID
    $_SESSION[Email]=$userEmail;

    //Remember first name
    $_SESSION[Fname] = $data;

    //go to dashboard page
    header ("location: dashboard.php");}

}else{ 
      $error2="Email and Password do not match, please try again."; 
    }
```

Comment: Prepared statements aren't _needed_ but they're surely _recommended_. Your code above is almost assuredly vulnerable to SQL injection, assuming `$userEmail,$userPassword` originate from user input. What you have will work if it is a valid query with correctly escaped input variables.

Comment: Additionally, it's not recommended to nest `mysqli_query()` inside `mysqli_fetch_assoc()`, as any execution failure will not be correctly handled.

Comment: The array key quotes in `$_SESSION['Email']` are not optional either. PHP will issue a notice about an undefined constant `Email` and substitute `'Email'`. Turn on error reporting and you'll see PHP is complaining about that `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: Thanks Michael!  I have been working day and night for the last four months on my website and I am learning a lot, but there is still a long way to go.  I admire guys like you, thought it would be easy, but its not as there is never an end.  Hope to help others someday on Stackoverflow.  Thanks